# Slurm initialization fails in a Raspberry Pi cluster with Raspbian 9.4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, slurm

I am trying to set up [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html) in a Raspberry Pi cluster with Raspbian 9.4.

I am able to start `slurmctld`, but when I try to launch `slurmd` I get the following output:

```
pi@node1:~ $ slurmd -Dvvvc
slurmd: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmd: error: Domain socket directory /SHARED/slurm/var/slurmd.node1: 
No such file or directory
slurmd: Message aggregation disabled
slurmd: topology NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: route default plugin loaded
slurmd: debug2: Gathering cpu frequency information for 4 cpus
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: No specialized cores configured by default on this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: Reserved system memory limit not configured for this node
slurmd: debug2: read_slurm_cgroup_conf: No cgroup.conf file (/SHARED/slurm/confdir/cgroup.conf)
slurmd: debug2: _file_read_content: unable to open '(null)/freezer//release_agent' for reading : No such file or directory
slurmd: debug2: xcgroup_get_param: unable to get parameter 'release_agent' for '(null)/freezer/'
slurmd: error: cgroup namespace 'freezer' not mounted. aborting
slurmd: error: unable to create freezer cgroup namespace
slurmd: error: Couldn't load specified plugin name for proctrack/cgroup: 
Plugin init() callback failed
slurmd: error: cannot create proctrack context for proctrack/cgroup
slurmd: error: slurmd initialization failed
```

My configuration file is:

```
ClusterName=Cluster
ControlMachine=node1
SlurmUser=pi
SlurmdUser=pi
AuthType=auth/none
CryptoType=crypto/openssl
JobCredentialPrivateKey = /SHARED/slurm/confdir/slurm.key
JobCredentialPublicCertificate = /SHARED/slurm/confdir/slurm.cert
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmdDebug=3

StateSaveLocation=/SHARED/slurm/var
SlurmdSpoolDir=/SHARED/slurm/var/slurmd.%n
SlurmctldPidFile=/SHARED/slurm/var/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/SHARED/slurm/var/slurmd.%n.pid

FastSchedule=2
SlurmctldLogFile=/SHARED/slurm/var/slurmctld.log
SlurmdLogFile=/SHARED/slurm/var/slurmd.%n.log

NodeName=node1 CPUs=4 SocketsPerBoard=4 CoresPerSocket=1 
ThreadsPerCore=1 RealMemory=976 TmpDisk=8212

PartitionName=main Nodes=node1 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

What an I missing?

Comment: Have you tried running `slurmd` with `sudo` privileges?

Comment: Yes, same results

Comment: `read_slurm_cgroup_conf: No cgroup.conf file (/SHARED/slurm/confdir/cgroup.conf)` is this file present?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that cgroup has not been properly configured. You can either configure this or change the proc tracking type.

Within the slurm.conf file there should be a variable called ProctrackType. If you want to change it to a solution that will work without cgroup you can set it to:

```
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
```

If the variable does not exist you can simply add this line as well.

Comment: Very nice, late answer!